# Which is the good UI framework vaadin or Ext-GWT ? Please suggest if anything else is better

Tags: vaadin, gxt

I have not used both the frameworks. When i went through a analysis both seem good and provided lots of controls. Still i am confused on choosing a framework. I wont liquid framework which will help the user to align the controls as they wish. Can i you know which framework will provide such feature ?

Comment: Vaadin's alignment mechanism is powerful but simple to use: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#LayoutAlignment - if that does not fill your requirements more exotic stuff can be done with CSS.

Answer (score 6):

> I did not use ext gwt but it looks promosing.
>
> On the other hand I have used vaadin as is very very good comparing to several other well > known frameworks and very easy to code for most of the thing.

im new to vaadin but i think is a good framework, one of the best

Answer (score 1):

I did not use ext gwt but it looks promosing.

On the other hand I have used vaadin as is very very good comparing to several other well known frameworks and very easy to code for most of the thing.

Answer (score 1):

actually, it depends what infrastructure and GUI you like, with extGWT you can follow GWT principles - you client side logic runs solely in the browser and your server code runs on the server, even the server does not need to be on java platform. JSON/XML/RPC etc can be used as data interchange protocol between server and client.

Vaadin, for instance, provides you a framework where you dont have to separate client vs server side code, you just code against Vaadin's API. In the end Vaadin levereges GWT to perform rendering tasks in the browser.

ExtGWT feels more like a frame application, whereas Vaadin is more Web-like, this is my personal opinion.

For my project I decided to take Vaadin instead of ExtGWT because of its licensing terms. ExtGWT's GPLv3 license did not fit to me, whereas Vaadin's Apache 2.0 did.